# Python: Generate C-Array from PIL Raw Pixel Data

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to generate a fixed width C Header / Include from a TrueType font.
The conversion to a fixed-width bitmap already works.

```
import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image

fontSize = 32
fontWidth = 20
numFonts = 1
numChars = 127-32 # Because the first 32 characters are not visible.

image = Image.new( 'RGB', (fontWidth*numChars,fontSize*numFonts), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("whitrabt.ttf", fontSize)
font2 = ImageFont.truetype("saxmono.ttf", fontSize)
font3 = ImageFont.truetype("MODENINE.TTF", fontSize)

# ASCII Characters from 32 DEC to 127 are visible
for x in range(32,127):
        draw.text(((x-32)*20, 0),chr( x), font=font)
        draw.text(((x-32)*20, 32),chr( x), font=font2)
        draw.text(((x-32)*20, 64),chr( x), font=font3)

// Convert to Grayscale for Grayscale LCD
image = image.convert('L')
image.show()
```

This works properly, but somehow I cannot get it managed
to output the pixel data as C-Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the pixels data using the `load()` method.

```
pixels = image.load()
```

If you want all the pixels in one big C array, you could do something like this:

```
print 'const char pixels[] = {'
w, h = image.size    
for y in range(h):
    print '\t',
    for x in range(w):
        print pixels[x,y], ',',
    print
print '};'
```

(For grayscale images, `pixels` will contain integers, for color images it will be (R,G,B) tuples.)